# Check request param beginning of each controller method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on spring mvc project. Here in each controller i have multiple method assigned to specific url. e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accountDetails")
public String home(HttpServletRequest request){
    Book book = (Book) request.getSession().getAttribute("Book");
    if (book == null) return "redirect:/";
    //other things to do here
    return "home";
}
```

Here I want to check session variable Book is empty or not at the beginning of each method. if it is return to / otherwise do some operation.

Is there any other way to check this null and return rather that the i have done it in the above code. I don't want write the same code at the beginning to each controller method.

So please suggest me an alternative way

Comment: Depending on the scope of "every method", you probably want controller advice or a handler interceptor, as described in the documentation.

Comment: could you please point me to some link or sample code. I am new to spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are several solutions. As pointed out by @chrylis, you can use [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-controller-advice), [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) or even a plain [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) (or it's [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) Spring flavour) for a generic, cross-cutting solution. Depending on your current project setup and your requirements one may be easier to implement than the other and it may or may not fit your needs, so make sure to just read the docs and decide if it fits your purpose.

Another approach with a fully programmatic solution would be to use a utility method with Java 8 lambda for the code block that you want to be executed in case `book` is available.

```
public static String withBook(Function<Book, String> bookOperation) {
    Book book = (Book) RequestContextHolder
            .currentRequestAttributes()
            .getAttribute("Book", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
    if (book == null) {
        return "redirect:/";
    } else {
        return bookOperation.apply(book);
    }
}
```

[`RequestContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) gives you access to the attributes of the current request and session.

You can use the utility method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accountDetails")
public String home() {
    return withBook(book -> {
        // just implement the part where book is not null
        return "home";
    });
}
```